# How to create addPlayer() method. (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, oop, methods, attributes

I'm currently working on an OOP project in my CSI class in which I have to create various sports team and athlete objects as well as a method addPlayer() for adding the athletes to a roster. This is what I have so far.

```
class Athlete:

def __init__(self, name, number):
    self.name = name
    self.number = number

def __str__(self):
    return "Athlete(" + self.name + ", " + self.number + ")"

def name(self):
    return self.name

def number(self):
    return self.number
```

---

```
from Athlete import *

class SportsTeam:

    roster = []

    def __init__(self, city, name, colors):
        self.city = city
        self.name = name
        self.colors = colors
        SportsTeam.roster = roster

    def __str__(self):
        return "SportsTeam(" + self.city + ", " + self.name + \
              ", " + str(self.colors) + ", " + ")"

    def getcity(self):
        return self.city

    def getname(self):
        return self.name

    def getcolors(self):
        return self.colors

    def getRoster(self):
        return SportsTeam.roster

    def printRoster(self):
        for player in roster:
            print("Current Team Roster: " + str(SportsTeam.roster))

    def addPlayer(self, player):
        SportsTeam.roster.append(player)
        return SportsTeam.roster
```

The thing is when I try to use the addPlayer() method I created, I get an error message telling me that list has no attribute. Not sure what needs to be added to fix this.

P.S I have only been programming for a couple of months, so I apologize if the solution is obvious

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with classes, you have your *instance variables* (like `self.city = city`) and your *class variables* (like `roster = []`).

Instance variables are tied to an instance of the class. So if you create 2 `SportsTeam` objects, they each have their own `city`.

Class variables are a little different. They are not tied to an instance of the class; meaning, no matter how many `SportsTeam` objects you create, there will only be one `roster` variable.

To me, `roster` being a class variable seems a bit odd because each `SportsTeam` should have its own `roster`. However, if you are required to use class variables for you CSI class, maybe you could keep a list of `all_teams` and/or `all_players`.

Taking this into consideration:

```
class SportsTeam:

    all_teams = []
    all_players = []

    def __init__(self, city, name, colors):
        self.city = city
        self.name = name
        self.colors = colors
        self.roster = []

        SportsTeam.all_teams.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "SportsTeam(" + self.city + ", " + self.name + ", " + str(self.colors) + ")"

    def getCity(self):
        return self.city

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getColors(self):
        return self.colors

    def getRoster(self):
        return self.roster

    def printRoster(self):
        # the for loop was unnecessary
        print("Current Team Roster:", str(self.roster))

    def addPlayer(self, player):
        SportsTeam.all_players.append(player)
        self.roster.append(player)
        return self.roster
```

If you would like to keep `roster` as a class variable, leave a comment and I can help you adjust the code to accommodate for this.